# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему FindFirst не может найти файл?

Tags: lazarus

var
  searchResult : TSearchRec;
begin
  //
  //
  // PATH SEARCHING
  if FindFirst(MangasName.Text + '.txt', faAnyFile, searchResult) = 0 then
  ListBox1.Items.SaveToFile(searchResult.Name)
  else
  begin
    if SaveDialog1.Execute then
    ListBox1.Items.SaveToFile(SaveDialog1.FileName);
  end;
  FindClose(searchResult);
  // PATH SEARCHING
  //
  //
end;

Comment: Потому что в текущей папке нет такого файла?

Comment: Что даёт кокатенация `MangasName.Text + '.txt'` и какова текущая директория?

Comment: MangasName.Text - это Edit, в котором прописано название файла. "+ '.txt'" - это расширение файла. Мне нужно, чтобы файл был найден вне директории с программой. И, судя по комментариям, как раз в этом то и ошибка. А не подскажите, как искать файл вообще на жёстких дисках?